# How to solve no output problem when I use vectors of vector to implement a graph data structure?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, graph

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std; 

class Graph{
    int v;
    vector<vector<int> > adj;
    
    public:
        Graph(int v){
            this->v = v;
        }
        
        void addEdge(int x, int y){
            adj[x].push_back(y);
            adj[y].push_back(x);
        }   
        
        void displayGraph(){
            for(int i=0; i<this->v; i++){
                cout << i << " --> ";
                for(int j=0; j<adj[i].size(); j++){
                    cout << adj[i][j] << " ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }   
};

  
int main() 
{ 
    Graph g1(3);
    
    g1.addEdge(0, 1);
    g1.addEdge(0, 2);
    
    g1.displayGraph();
    
    return 0; 
}
```

I wanted to implement graph data structure using C++. therefore, I've created class called Graph and used vector of vector to create my adjacency list. I've used vector because I can allocate dynamically when I want. Also I have a constructor to set number of vertices. Then I have member function called `addEdge()`. And then I've `displayGraph()` function to display my graph.

problem is when I execute this it executes but it don't provide any output. Also in terminal it shows this. return value is not 0.

```
Process exited after 3.137 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graph(int v) {
    this->v = v;
    adj.resize(v); //do this
}
```

You have declared `adj` but `adj[x]` in `addEdge()` won't work because you are trying to access something for which memory hasn't been allocated. So, vector subscript will be out of range.

Now it prints:

```
0 --> 1 2
1 --> 0
2 --> 0
```